# Solving dice throwing and coin tossing problem using tensorflow probability, variance is wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, statistics, tensorflow-probability

I am not very proficient in Statistics, I am trying to learn. So please bear with me. I saw [this](https://www.quora.com/A-fair-dice-is-rolled-if-the-result-is-an-odd-number-then-a-fair-coin-is-tossed-3-times-Otherwise-if-the-result-is-even-number-then-a-fair-coin-will-be-tossed-2-times-In-both-cases-of-heads-is-counted-Whats-the?ch=99&share=bef02ae8&srid=nmId) question in Quora - Which basically states the following -

> A fair dice is rolled if the result is an odd number then a fair coin
>   is tossed 3 times. Otherwise, if the result is even number then a fair
>   coin will be tossed 2 times. In both cases, # of heads is counted.
>   What's the variance of # heads obtained?

I wanted to solve it using Python and tf-probability. Here is what I did -

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()
probs = [1/6.] * 6

dices = tfp.distributions.Multinomial(total_count=1000, probs=probs)

n = dices.sample()

HEAD = 1
TAIL = 0
l = list(n.numpy())
heads_even = []
heads_odd = []
for i, nums in enumerate(l):
    mul_by = 3 if (i + 1) % 2 != 0 else 2
    tosses = tfp.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=0.5)
    coin_flip_data = tosses.sample(nums * mul_by)
    l2 = coin_flip_data.numpy()
    unique, counts = np.unique(l2, return_counts=True)
    head_tails = dict(zip(unique, counts))
    if (i + 1) % 2 != 0:
        heads_odd.append(head_tails[HEAD])
    else:
        heads_even.append(head_tails[HEAD])

total_heads = heads_odd + heads_even
final_nd_arr = np.array(total_heads)
print(final_nd_arr.var())
```

However, the `final_nd_arr.var()` is of course nowhere near to the actual answer (it is 2089.805555555556) , 0.68 (As people have mentioned in the Quora answer).

I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong. How can I rectify my mistake?

Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

--------- EDIT

To give more data,

```
dices.sample() => array([169., 173., 149., 171., 175., 163.], dtype=float32)
heads_odd => [266, 210, 259]
heads_even => [176, 167, 145]
total_heads => [266, 210, 259, 176, 167, 145]
```

Comment: What answer do you get?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the value I am getting. @EdekiOkoh

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that if you are running this code you may a get a different value for the `final_nd_arr.var()` at the end due to the stochastic nature of the code.

Comment: True but the answer should converge to the same result if u run it enough times (stats major here)

Comment: Agree, but that is not my point. I wanted to understand what is off in my understanding, why am I not getting a value close to 0.68 (I was ready to accept that doing this experiment enough amount of time will converge to 0.68, but this does not look like the case here at least) Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No it will not converge even if you increase the number of iterations. I am reviewing the code and looking for the error. It is most likely because of total_heads. Can you show the print of total_heads, heads_odd, tails_odd?

Comment: I have added the data from my run in the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are computing the variance over the wrong distribution. The variance we are looking for applies to the experiment where you would roll the dice over and over again, each time count the number of heads, and compute the variance over the number of heads. You are doing this in your code, but your are *summing* the total number of heads over all the dice rolls, and then taking the variance of these sums for each possible outcome of the dice.

This will give the correct result. I added some comments that hopefully clarify it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

# Simulate the outcome of 1000 dice rolls
probs = [1/6.] * 6
dices = tfp.distributions.Multinomial(total_count=1000, probs=probs)
n = dices.sample()
l = list(n.numpy().astype(int))

L = []
# Loop over 6 possible dice outcomes
for i in range(len(l)):
    # Loop over the rolls for this dice outcome
    for _ in range(l[i]):
        # For each of the dice rolls,
        # Flip a coin 2 or three times
        num_tosses = 3 if (i + 1) % 2 != 0 else 2
        tosses = tfp.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=0.5)
        coin_flip_data = tosses.sample(num_tosses)

        # And count the number of heads
        num_heads = np.sum(coin_flip_data.numpy())
        L += [num_heads]

np.var(L)
> 0.668999
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It totally makes sense now!!